# Slider Style: Gradient along the width of the groove

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols

I am trying to create a custom QML `Slider` style as follows:

```
SliderStyle {
    groove: Item {
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        implicitWidth: 500
        implicitHeight: 10
        Rectangle {
            radius: height/2
            anchors.fill: parent
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "#888"
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { color: "#0A406E" ; position: 0 }
                GradientStop { color: "#FFA800" ; position: 1 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the gradient on the groove here is going from `top` to `bottom` rather than `left` to `right`. I tried swapping the `width` and `height` values and rotating the `Rectangle` by -90 degrees but then the slider was unresponsive. Also, I could never get the rotation to be done along the centre of the slider control, which made placement a bit problematic.

I was wondering if there is a way to achieve this left->right gradient flow.

Comment: Rotating the gradient is the only way to go, unfortunately QML is not exactly big on gradients. Although you could use a shader effect as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rectangle`'s property `gradient` allows for the construction of simple vertical gradients. For more complex gradients there are [`LinearGradient`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-lineargradient.html), [`RadialGradient`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-radialgradient.html) and [`ConicalGradient`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtgraphicaleffects-conicalgradient.html) types.

For example, horizontal gradient:

```
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

SliderStyle {
    groove: Item {
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        implicitWidth: 500
        implicitHeight: 10
        Rectangle {
            radius: height/2
            anchors.fill: parent
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "#888"
            layer.enabled: true
            layer.effect: LinearGradient {
                start: Qt.point(0, 0)
                end: Qt.point(500, 0)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#0A406E" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#FFA800" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```